# Extend ReSharper's Unit Test Sessions window

Tags: resharper, resharper-sdk

Is it possible to extend (eg. add a menu item to a context menu in) ReSharper's **Unit Test Sessions** window?

What I'd like to achieve is to be able to select one or more tests and then apply a custom category attribute to those tests (eg. modify the respective test's method or class to add an attribute like `[NeedsFixing]`.

Comment: Isn't every test that fails in need of fixing? :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at Victor Kropps [TestToolsPlugin](https://github.com/kropp/ReSharper-TestToolsPlugin), which has kind of the same functionality.

Comment: Looks like it has just what I was looking for "Mark test with category from Unit Test Session (with suggests based on categories used in solution)"